# nesting javascript remote method calls

Tags: javascript-remoting

I have a scenario where i need to call two remote action methods.  Second method needs an input parameter which is the output of first method.  Can i nest the second remote call into first one. Is there anything wrong in doing this ? Is there any better approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can nest them.  Your invocation of the second method should be in the callback of the first method.  See this post:

[Is it possible to execute remote functions in order?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71066/is-it-possible-to-execute-remote-functions-in-order)